# 14.04 LTS on a Dell XPS 2015 only boots with nomodeset

Tags: drivers

as the title says, I'm running 14.04 on a Dell XPS 2015 with Intel Broadwell Graphics. I need to pass `nomodeset` to the kernel to boot it. I can't playback video in full screen and the wireless dies after a suspend, so its not an ideal solution.

Some info on my setup:

```
# lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)

# lshw -C video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)

# modinfo i915
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
srcversion:     4DEE70267367E5F1E3B45B0
alias:          pci:v00008086d000022B3sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
[...]
alias:          pci:v00008086d000022B2sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
depends:        drm_kms_helper,drm,video,i2c-algo-bit
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        AC:F6:91:81:39:AD:3F:CA:CC:01:C2:6A:B2:49:09:D5:90:79:A5:78
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           modeset:Use kernel modesetting [KMS] (0=DRM_I915_KMS from .config, 1=on, -1=force vga console preference [default]) (int)
parm:           panel_ignore_lid:Override lid status (0=autodetect, 1=autodetect disabled [default], -1=force lid closed, -2=force lid open) (int)
parm:           powersave:Enable powersavings, fbc, downclocking, etc. (default: true) (int)
parm:           semaphores:Use semaphores for inter-ring sync (default: -1 (use per-chip defaults)) (int)
parm:           enable_rc6:Enable power-saving render C-state 6. Different stages can be selected via bitmask values (0 = disable; 1 = enable rc6; 2 = enable deep rc6; 4 = enable deepest rc6). For example, 3 would enable rc6 and deep rc6, and 7 would enable everything. default: -1 (use per-chip default) (int)
parm:           enable_fbc:Enable frame buffer compression for power savings (default: -1 (use per-chip default)) (int)
parm:           lvds_downclock:Use panel (LVDS/eDP) downclocking for power savings (default: false) (int)
parm:           lvds_channel_mode:Specify LVDS channel mode (0=probe BIOS [default], 1=single-channel, 2=dual-channel) (int)
parm:           lvds_use_ssc:Use Spread Spectrum Clock with panels [LVDS/eDP] (default: auto from VBT) (int)
parm:           vbt_sdvo_panel_type:Override/Ignore selection of SDVO panel mode in the VBT (-2=ignore, -1=auto [default], index in VBT BIOS table) (int)
parm:           reset:Attempt GPU resets (default: true) (bool)
parm:           enable_hangcheck:Periodically check GPU activity for detecting hangs. WARNING: Disabling this can cause system wide hangs. (default: true) (bool)
parm:           enable_ppgtt:Override PPGTT usage. (-1=auto [default], 0=disabled, 1=aliasing, 2=full) (int)
parm:           enable_psr:Enable PSR (default: false) (int)
parm:           preliminary_hw_support:Enable preliminary hardware support. (int)
parm:           disable_power_well:Disable the power well when possible (default: true) (int)
parm:           enable_ips:Enable IPS (default: true) (int)
parm:           fastboot:Try to skip unnecessary mode sets at boot time (default: false) (bool)
parm:           prefault_disable:Disable page prefaulting for pread/pwrite/reloc (default:false). For developers only. (bool)
parm:           invert_brightness:Invert backlight brightness (-1 force normal, 0 machine defaults, 1 force inversion), please report PCI device ID, subsystem vendor and subsystem device ID to dri-devel@lists.freedesktop.org, if your machine needs it. It will then be included in an upcoming module version. (int)
parm:           disable_display:Disable display (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_vtd_wa:Disable all VT-d workarounds (default: false) (bool)
parm:           enable_cmd_parser:Enable command parsing (1=enabled [default], 0=disabled) (int)
```